# Number of digits printed in C program

Tags: c

How can I variably influence the number of digits printed in C program?I do not want to write unnecessary zeros in decimal development

x=7
Output: 7

x=7.700
Output 7.7

x=7.77700
Output: 7.777

My point is not to have fixed printf ("%. 3lf", yourVariable); , but but it changed variably on the values ​​I would send there

Comment: In a scientific context, 7.7 is something else than 7.700. How could we know which decimals are "unnecessary"?

Comment: here I have normal decimal notation numbers, all zeros in the example are unnecessary

Comment: do you want to remove all unnecessary 0 from decimal number? like you write 5.34000000 and the output should be 5.34?

Comment: @Karnal-YK yes.

Comment: @Aaron7 you can simply use type conversion for it. Take any number and convert it to float. As I show in answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of `%g` [Format Specifier](https://www.javatpoint.com/c-format-specifier) in C for this.

[Working Fiddle](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/7m9zvcA)

Working Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {   
    float number;
   
    printf("Enter an integer: ");  
    
    // reads and stores input
    scanf("%f", &number);

    // displays output
    printf("You entered: %g", number);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: May want to comment that if the values are `double` then `%lf` will be needed for `scanf()`. Worthy of UV for firm understanding of the `g` conversion specifier.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is a way to dynamically change the precision of the output without having to hardcode it.

If you have access to a c99 compiler, you can generate format strings by using `snprintf` like:

```
char* format_width(double x, unsigned prec) {
  int fmt_size = snprintf (NULL, 0, "%%.%ulf", prec);
  char* fmt_string = malloc(fmt_size + 1);
  snprintf(fmt_string, fmt_size + 1, "%%.%ulf", prec);
  
  int out_size = snprintf (NULL, 0, fmt_string, x);
  char* out_string = malloc(out_size + 1);
  snprintf(out_string, out_size + 1, fmt_string, x);
  
  free(fmt_string);
  return out_string;
}
```

#### Usage could be something like

```
int main() {   
    double number;
    unsigned prec;
   
    printf("Enter a number: ");  
    
    // reads and stores input
    scanf("%lf", &number);
    
    printf("Enter precision: ");  
    
    // reads and stores precision
    scanf("%u", &prec);
    
    char* result = format_width(number, prec);
    // displays output
    printf("You entered: %s", result);
    
    free(result);
    
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/Cc7Ktu1)

---

#### Optimizing allocations

In order to avoid too many allocations, one could make use of a buffer of reasonable size to generate the format specifier. For example, it is very unlikely that the `fmt_string` will ever exceed 15 characters, so we can optimize that part.

It may also be possible that the user already knows the maximum size of input they may ever receive, so we can allow them to pass in the `out_string` buffer (which is assumed to be large enough to contain the result)

```
char* format_width(double x, unsigned prec, char* out_string) {
  static char fmt_string[15];
  snprintf(fmt_string, 15, "%%.%ulf", prec);

  int out_size = snprintf (NULL, 0, fmt_string, x);
  snprintf(out_string, out_size + 1, fmt_string, x);
  
  return out_string;
}
```

Comment: Worthy of UV for `snprintf (NULL, 0 ...` trick for sizing the number of characters needed. But consider passing an array of automatic-storage duration (of reasonable sufficient size) as 3rd parameter to avoid allocating storage and eliminate placing the burden of freeing the storage in case the function is called in a loop. Could become a hot-spot if the user is scanning a large number of floating-point values.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply convert it to a float number

```
x = (float)x;
```

IT will remove all the unnecessary 0.